# Use next and prev() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label for="a1">First:</label>
<input id="a1" class="first" type="text" name="a1" value="123">
<label for="b1">Second:</label>
<input id="b1" class="second" type="text" name="b1"> <br />
<label for="a2">First:</label>
<input id="a2" class="first" type="text" name="a2"value="3424">
<label for="b2">Second:</label>
<input id="b2" class="second" type="text" name="b2"> <br />
<label for="a3">First:</label>
<input id="a3" class="first" type="text" name="a3"value="1235">
<label for="b3">Second:</label>
<input id="b3" class="second" type="text" name="b3"> <br />

$('.second').click(function(){
   var get_first = // ???
   $(this).val(get_first);
})
```

i would like for example - if i click on input b3 then in this value now is value from a3. how can i make it with next and prev in one class?

http://jsfiddle.net/Bgkrz/

Comment: Wait, on focusing `#b3` you want the input to be populated automatically with the value from input `#a3`? Wouldn't this, by definition mean that all inputs end up with the same value as the first of all the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I can think of a reason for doing this, but assuming I understand your requirements correctly, then this should work (currently untested):

```
$('input:text').focus(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.val(that.prevAll('input:text:first').val());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gyUHk/1/).

References:

- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
- [`:text` selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this [JsFiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bgkrz/1/)

```
$('.second').click(function(){
   var get_first = $(this).prev().prev().val();
   $(this).val(get_first);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/Bgkrz/2/)

Use `jQuery.prevAll()` It'll return the array in reverse order, you can find the element at zero index here.